# Передача regexp переменной и границы слова

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Передо мной стоит задача проверить строку на соответствие значения, передаваемого с переменной. При этом необходимо указать границу слова. Нечто вроде этого:

```
var sa="Sample";
var re=new RegExp(/\b/+sa);
alert(re.test("Sample text"));
```

К сожалению, что-то здесь не так. Ответа пока нигде не нашёл. Было бы здорово получить его здесь! :)

Comment: Неправильно конструируете регулярное выражение. `/\b/` создает новый объект регексов, а далее Вы пытаетесь сложить его со строкой sa. Это неверно.  
В конструктор RegExp надо передавать две строки: выражение и модификаторы. Оба параметра строковые.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var sa = 'Sample';
var re = new RegExp('\\b' + sa);
alert(re.test("Sample text"));
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает.